# Azure Stream ANalytics - Find Most Recent `n` Events Within Time Interval

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I am working with Azure Stream Analytics and, to illustrate my situation, I have streaming events corresponding to buy(+)/sell(-) orders from users of a certain amount. So, key fields in an individual event look like: `{UserId: 'u12345', Type: 'Buy', Amt: 14.0}`.

I want to write a query which outputs `UserId`'s and the sum of `Amt` for the most recent (up to) 5 events within a sliding 24 hr period partitioned by `UserId`.

To clarify:

1. If there are more than 5 events for a given `UserId` in the last 24 hours, I only want the sum of `Amt` for the most recent 5.
2. If there are fewer than 5 events, I either want the `UserId` to be omitted or the sum of the `Amt` of the events that do exist.

I've tried looking at `LIMIT DURATION` predicates, but there doesn't seem to be a way to limit the number of events as well as filter on time while `PARTITION`'ing by `UserId`. Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: Could you please confirm and clarify the requirement?

In a 24h sliding window, calculate C = Count(*) GROUP BY UserId. Then for each UserId:
- If C > 5, grab only the last 5 events and return sum(Amt)
- If C <= 5, not sure what's happening here. Is that sum(Amt), or nothing?

Comment: Yea - that's the right idea, but SlidingWindow is a bit problematic as it outputs as events exit. So, for 6 orders, say, in 24 hours I'd get an output when the last order exits the Window even though no buy/sell order occurred. Not desirable, but, additionally, the "grab only the last 5" part is the tricky aspect here. Collect and CollectTop don't seem to be able to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the requirement then. Without thinking about ASA at all. Would you say you want 1 output every time you see 5 orders from the same user in less than 24 hour? Is that running 24h, or per day?

Comment: Which means that if a user send 4 records within an hour, then nothing for 25h, you would see nothing out.

Comment: Yes - Ideally one output of the last 5 orders within a 24 hr running window. 

Correct that if a user placed 4 and nothing for 25 then it's fine if nothing shows.

In my use-case, there will almost certainly be more than 5 in a given window, and the key question is how to limit to a most recent 5 within a rolling timewindow. Users with less than 5 in that window aren't important.

Comment: Ok that makes sense for the lower bound. Now for the upper bound, if a user has 5000 orders in 24h, do you need 1 record out? Or 4992 (the first 4 and last 4 orders are ignored since their windows will have less than 5). If it's one, when do we reset the time window? Is it estimated once every 24h? Or refreshed on a shorter time period (let's say every 1h, but still looking at the last 24h) - in which case here you will receive 24 records out? Or something more complex?

Comment: Ah yea. If all of those occured within 24 hrs of each other, it should output 4995 events (an output as each event is processed) each with the most recent 5 Amt summed. That is, as a new event comes in it needs to look back and gather the most recent 5 within 24hrs and sum the amount and output (if there are are at least 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the comments, I think this should work:

```
WITH Last5 AS (
    SELECT
        UserId,
        System.Timestamp() AS windowEnd,
        COLLECTTOP(5) OVER (ORDER BY CAST(EventEnqueuedUtcTime AS DATETIME) DESC) AS Top5
    FROM    input1
    TIMESTAMP BY EventEnqueuedUtcTime
    GROUP BY
        SlidingWindow(hour,24),
        UserId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5 --We want at least 5
)

SELECT
    L.UserId,
    System.Timestamp() AS ts,
    SUM(C.ArrayValue.value.Amt) AS sumAmt
INTO myOutput
FROM Last5 AS L
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(L.Top5) AS C
GROUP BY
    System.Timestamp(), --Snapshot window
    L.UserId
```

We use a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/with-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) to first get the sliding window of 24h. In there we both filter to only retain windows of more than 5 records (`HAVING COUNT(*) > 5`), and collect only the last 5 of them (`COLLECTOP(5) OVER...`). Note that I had to `TIMESTAMP BY` and `CAST` on my own timestamp when testing the query, you may not need that in your case.

Next we need to unpack the collected records, that's done via `CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements`, and sum them. I use a [snapshot window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/snapshot-window-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) for that, as I don't need time grouping on that one.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm going to adapt this to my use-case. I was looking at `CROSS APPLY` and `COLLECTTOP`, but coultn't get that to work properly. I kept getting what felt like "extra" subsets of 5 orders within the window. I'll update as I work through it

Comment: Ok - this is looking good. However, as I run this locally (VS Code), I see in the `COLLECTTOP` array for the intermediate step that several events have the same `rank` value. These appear to also share the same `EventQueuedTime`, which makes me think this is an artifact of job start-up causing them to stack-up at the exact same timestamp?

Comment: Looking at it more, I think this is correct, but validation is tricky since the duplicate `rank` fields in the `COLLECTTOP` result array (caused by equal EnqueuedTime) result in the sum aggregating over more than 5 events. I don't think this will happen in the live stream, however.